# How to filter JSON with nested object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON with nested object. It looks like this:

```
var cars = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Ford Focus", 
        "attributes":{
            "color":"gray",
            "speed":"200"
        }
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Ford Fiesta", 
        "attributes":{
            "color":"red",
            "speed":"180"
        }
    },
];
```

I want to filter by values in nested object (for example all cars with green color).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `filter()` method

```js
var cars = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Ford Focus", 
        "attributes":{
            "color":"gray",
            "speed":"200"
        }
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Ford Fiesta", 
        "attributes":{
            "color":"red",
            "speed":"180"
        }
    },
]; 

console.log(cars.filter(car => car.attributes.color === 'red'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer use `lodash` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.13#filter

or

you can use this simple snippet

```
var redCars = cars.filter(car=>car.attributes.color==='red');

console.log(redCars);
```

working sample https://jsbin.com/tazumubopu/edit?js,console